# How to tell automake generated Makefile to execute a script before compiling?

Tags: makefile, automake

Is there a way to tell automake that you want to execute a command (like a touch in a .cpp file) every time before compiling ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual use case?

Comment: @jørgensen, maybe it's an office prank.  If the right file is touched, the object of the prank could type 'make' at the terminal all day...

Comment: The actual case: we want to force recompilation of some .cpp, even if they are not touched, to launch some macroes. In fact, this is just the excuses that let me discover I don't know how to just launch whatever command using Automake just before starting compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but you can tell `make` to imagine that a file's out of date. Use `AM_MAKEFLAGS`:

```
AM_MAKEFLAGS = -W$(top_srcdir)/src/why_are_you_doing_this.cc
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the same result in a quicker / smoother / more intelligent way that I am missing ?

Comment: @St0rM: Add more context to your question and perhaps the community can find a more helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.PHONY : touchcpp
touchcpp :
    touch foo.cpp
all : touchcpp
```

This sounds like a possible way to build forever...